# How to push a js object to a json array using postgreSQL?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

Im using supabase. i have a json array column in a table. it is a little difficult to push an object to it. i should get that json array, push an object to it and update that column. i should send two requests and its not what i want because it makes some problem in my web app.

I was looking for answer and i found postgreSQL. I can create my custom query and i can for example write a query that takes an object and push that to a column. And thankfully i can use it in supabase. But i have a lot of problem in using this. Can you please tell me how can i write a query that gets an object and push that object to a column in supabase?

I tested some queries. I found some json methodes in postgreSQL document and i tested them but i got error. Thanks for helping

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.